# Mapping a page with a specific address

Tags: memory-management, virtual-address-space, windows64, virtualalloc

I'm trying to map a virtual memory page using VirtualAlloc, but it's an specific address outside 8TB Windows 7 64 bits allowed range, i've read at Windows Internals book this address range is used 
for "page table self mapping structures", anyway,is there any way i could map a memory page with the 0x7ffffffff000 address?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to map a physical memory page whose physical absolute address you know?

Comment: I'm trying to map a virtual mem page